# sentence level encoding using Keras

Tags: keras, deep-learning, python-3.6, lstm, attention-model

My task is to build a supervised model for text similarity using Keras. My input is a pair of long form texts and target is 0 or 1. I am trying to encode words within a sentence for each text. The purpose is to derive knowledge from different levels of a document structure.For this, I first split the text into a list of sentences, then tokenize. I also fix the max_sentence_length (maximum number of sentences in a text) and max_sequence_length (max words within a sentence). Below is my code for pre-processing:

```
input_text1 = [sen.split('.') for sen in input_text1]
input_text2 = [sen.split('.') for sen in input_text2]

max_words = 20000 (vocab size)
max_sequence_length = 500
max_sentence_length = 100
emb_dim = 50
n_classes = 2
latent_dim = 128
lr = 0.001
epochs = 20
batch_size = 128

tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=max_words, filters='!"#$%&()*+,-.:;=?@[\\]^_`{|}~\t\n', lower=True, split=' ', oov_token="UNK")
encoder = LabelEncoder()
tr_sent1, te_sent1, tr_sent2, te_sent2, tr_rel, te_rel = train_test_split(input_text1, input_text2, similarity, test_size=0.2, stratify=similarity)
input_text_sen1 = tr_sent1[:2]
input_text_sen2 = tr_sent2[:2]
tr_rel = tr_rel[:2]
for sen in input_text_sen1 + input_text_sen2:
    tokenizer.fit_on_texts(sen)
encoder.fit(tr_rel)
tokenizer.word_index = {e: i for e, i in tokenizer.word_index.items() if i <= max_words}
tokenizer.word_index[tokenizer.oov_token] = max_words + 1
seqs1 = []
for sen in input_text_sen1:
    tmp = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(sen)
    seqs1.append(tmp)

# to fix the number of sentences

seqs1_fixed = []
for sen in seqs1:
    sen = sen[:max_sentence_length]
    seqs1_fixed.append(sen)
seqs1_fixed = [pad_sequences(sen, maxlen=max_sequence_length,
                             value=0, padding='post', truncating='post') for sen in seqs1_fixed]

seqs2 = []
for sen in input_text_sen2:
    tmp = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(sen)
    seqs2.append(tmp)

seqs2_fixed = []
for sen in seqs2:
    sen = sen[:max_sentence_length]
    seqs2_fixed.append(sen)

seqs2_fixed = [pad_sequences(sen, maxlen=max_sequence_length,
                             value=0, padding='post', truncating='post') for sen in seqs2_fixed]
categorical_y = encoder.transform(tr_rel)
```

Below is the code for building the model:

```
bilstm = Bidirectional(LSTM(units=latent_dim, return_sequences=True, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2))

encoder_input1 = [Input(shape=(max_sentence_length,), name='desc_word_' + str(i + 1)) for i in range(max_sequence_length)] # list with each shape=(None, 100)
text_embedding_input1 = Embedding(input_dim=max_words+2, output_dim=emb_dim, input_length=max_sentence_length)  # list with each shape=(None, 100, 50)
embedding_input1 = [text_embedding_input1(inp) for inp in encoder_input1]
words_concat1 = concatenate(embedding_input1, axis=-1) # shape=(None, 100, 25000)
bilstm_out1 = bilstm(words_concat1) # shape=(None, 100, 256)

encoder_input2 = [Input(shape=(max_sentence_length, ), name='desc_word_' + str(i + 1)) for i in range(max_sequence_length)]
text_embedding_input2 = Embedding(input_dim=max_words+2, output_dim=emb_dim, input_length=max_sentence_length)
embedding_input2 = [text_embedding_input2(inp) for inp in encoder_input2]
words_concat2 = concatenate(embedding_input2, axis=-1)
bilstm_out2 = bilstm(words_concat2)

x1 = attention()(bilstm_out1) # shape=(None, 256)
x1 = Dropout(0.2)(x1)
x2 = attention()(bilstm_out2) # shape=(None, 256)
x2 = Dropout(0.2)(x2)
x = concatenate([x1, x2]) # shape=(None, 512)
out = Dense(units=n_classes, activation="softmax", kernel_regularizer=l2(0.01), bias_regularizer=l2(0.01))(x) # shape=(None, 2)
model = Model([encoder_input1 + encoder_input2], out)
```

Right now I get below error on running model:

```
ValueError: Input tensors to a Model must come from `keras.layers.Input`. Received: [<tf.Tensor 'desc_word_1_16:0' shape=(None, 100) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'desc_word_2_16:0' shape=(None, 100) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'desc_word_3_16:0'....
```

Please advise on what is causing this error. I am stuck at it for a long time. Also, an alternate suggestions to tackle this issue is also welcome.

Answer (score 0):

In this line of code: `model = Model([encoder_input1 + encoder_input2], out)`,

modify it to `model = Model(inputs=[encoder_input1] + [encoder_input2], outputs=out)`

Comment: I tried modifying it but I am getting the same error.

Comment: Because your encoder_input1/2 is a list instead of a Tensor. Please modify your encoder_input1 and encoder_input2 to Input(shape=(max_sentence_length,), name='desc_word_') or something similar.

Comment: If I change that, I am afraid the next few lines will fail. The purpose of doing list comprehension was to feed list of inputs each having shape=(None, 100)  into the embedding layer. This is followed by words_concat1 = concatenate(embedding_input1, axis=-1) so that input to bilstm is a 3d tensor. Alternatively, if I do something like below instead of list comprehension: encoder_input1 = Input(shape=(max_sentence_length, max_sequence_length), name='desc_word_1')
           text_embedding_input1 = Embedding(input_dim=max_words+2, output_dim=emb_dim)(encoder_input1)  #shape=(None, 100, 500, 50)

Comment: I end up with 4d tensor which i cant feed into lstm. Please advise if there is a better way to deal with this issue.